# Pandas read_fwf: specify dtype

Tags: python, pandas, dtype

I am reading in a huge fixed width text file in chunks and export the data as
csv. Because ***pandas.read_fwf*** does not allow to specify the dtypes, I am
wondering what other way there exists to force the columns to be strings. The
reason is that pandas infers some columns as float even though they are not and
I do not want a `.0` within a column.

Using `data[column] = data[column].astype(str)` does not help as it will not get
rid of decimals. **Converting columns of float64 dtype to int doesn't work
either** since NAs cannot be converted. Any ideas?

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
dat = pd.read_fwf(file_to_read,colspecs=cols,header=None,chunksize=100000,names=header)
#First chunk
data.info()
Int64Index: 100000 entries, 0 to 99999
Columns: 562 entries,
dtypes: float64(405), int64(4), object(153)
memory usage: 429.5+ MB

for column in data.columns:
    if data[column].dtype == 'float64':
        data[column] = data[column].astype(int)
    else:
        pass
```

I could do `str().replace('.0','')`, but I want to find an easier way than
iterating through the column which takes a lot of time.

Comment: It does support dtype please check the documentation http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `converter` parameter can be used to preserve the data as strings since `pd.read_fwf` does not try to guess the dtype if a converter is specified:

```
import pandas as pd
try:
    # for Python2
    from cStringIO import StringIO 
except ImportError:
    # for Python3
    from io import StringIO

content = '''\
1.0    2    A
3.0    4    B
5      X    C
M      Y    D
'''
header = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']

for df in pd.read_fwf(StringIO(content), header=None, chunksize=2, names=header,
                      converters={h:str for h in header}):
    print(df)
df.info()
```

yields

```
   foo bar baz
0  1.0   2   A
1  3.0   4   B

  foo bar baz
0   5   X   C
1   M   Y   D

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 3 columns):
foo    2 non-null object
bar    2 non-null object
baz    2 non-null object
dtypes: object(3)
memory usage: 120.0+ bytes
```

Comment: Thanks for showing an example! It works perfectly. I was totally overlooking the converter option...